# PHP PDO obj works on PHP CLI, but not when page is accessed

Tags: php, ajax, sqlite, pdo

As a response to my previous question, I think I may have discovered which part isn't working correctly. I have a small section of PHP code which uses a PDO object to add to a sqlite3 database that is used in a AJAX call.

When this code is executed using the php cli by issuing the command: "php add.php" everything works as expected and adds and entry to the table. However when I access this php file by it's web address, nothing is added to the table.

```
$base = new PDO('sqlite:todo.db');
$sql = $base->prepare("INSERT INTO Tasks (content) VALUES ('testdata');");
$sql->execute();
echo "done";
```

"done" will appear at the command line, as well as on the webpage. Can anyone explain this strange behavior to me?

Comment: Throw in a `print_r($base->errorInfo());` at the end to see what information it yields.

Comment: Enable all possible error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL) ; ini_set('dispaly_errors', 1)` and check for any PDO errors after creating, preparing, and executing with the appropriate PDO error getting functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible explanations for this, but I'll venture to guess that the web user doesn't have access to write to the sqlite database file.

Comment: Wow, simple as that huh? I can't believe I spent like 2 days trying to fix this and didn't consider this possibility. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Is now the appropriate time to advice you *not* to use sqlite for a webapp, because it doesn't cope well (eg. at all) with concurrent users?